# python selenium права на запуск

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

При выполнении этого кода в PyCharm получаю ошибку

```
 import selenium.webdriver
    URL = 'www.ya.ru'
    phantom = 'C:\\phantomjs\\bin'
    driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantom)
    driver.get(URL)

  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'bin' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

Windows 10
Права админа есть. 
UAC отключил.
PyCharm запускаю с правами администратора.
Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

executable_path - это полный путь до исполняемого файла, а вас только до папки. Допишите название файла

```
phantom = r'C:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe'
```

Answer (score 2):

Может надо добавить путь к phantom в PATH
У меня была похожая ситуация с Chromedriver, помогло, добавив путь в PATH и запустив драйвер так: `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome() # без пути в скобках`